# How to reuse code in firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have my firebase cloud functions setup into individual files (functionName.f.js) and then my index.js file exports the files as functions with the following piece of code:

index.js file

```
for (let f = 0, fl = files.length; f < fl; f++) {
  const file = files[f];
  const functionName = camelCase(file.slice(0, -5).split('/').join('_')); // Strip off '.f.js'
  if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === functionName) {
    exports[functionName] = require(file);
  }

}

exports = module.exports.function1 = function1();
exports = module.exports.function2 = function2();

//omitted function1 and function2 code
```

I am trying to reuse code in multiple different function files. At the moment I have the functions I want to reuse in my 'index.js' file - i then reference the index.js file in whichever function file i want to call those functions in as follows:

function1.f.js file

```
const helpers = require('../index');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports = module.exports = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
await helpers.function1;
}
```

The problem is, when function1 is referenced like above - function2 seems to execute as well, even though its never called.

my eslintrc.json file's relevant section

```
  "parserOptions": {
    // Required for certain syntax usages
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
```

Comment: How do you see that the function 2 is called?

Comment: I have logs setup for each function executing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong with `exports` variable. I have replicated it and its working like this:

```
module.exports = {
        function1,
        function2 
}
```

and than call it with () like: `helpers.function1()`

This should be working properly.